# Is UI Chips for all single choice input a good idea?

Tags: mobile-application, input-fields, material-design, guidelines

I'm working on an iPhone/iPad app that uses a lot of forms and we are currently using several different components for input where the user have to do a single choice from a defined list of items. For example:

- Radio button in a list with 2 to 3 items.
- Segmented controller where there are 2-6 items to choose from.
- Dropdown with native date picker or time picker. Also used for long lists
- Material design style choice where you press a list item and it pushes in a screen with 5 or more choices.

I would like to find a better way to at least show the input component in the UI. Perhaps using Choice chips, Action chips, Input chips for all type of input? [Chips in Material design](https://material.io/components/chips)

I have tried to see if anyone has done this but cannot find it in any Google app or any other app.

What happens after pressing the chip would vary. for example, date input  would use the iOS Native date picker. But what I'm trying to do is to have *ONE* component to tell the user that a single choice from a set list of items are required.

Is there a reason for not doing it if I am consistent with always using chips for Actions, Input, Choice and Filter?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking standards is always risky but you can be pleasantly surprised when taking the prototype to your users. I say try it out, make a low fidelity prototype and test. If it makes sense to your users and it is something they catch on quickly then go for it!

Answer (score 0):

> But what I'm trying to do is to have ONE component to tell the user
> that a single choice from a set list of items are required.

Firstly, you have two requirements here: (1) single choice, and (2) a required action.

Let's get (2) out of the way: show it with a star or other similar indicators. It has nothing to do with your main component, i.e. *choosing something* is required, not *single choice*.

Regarding the component, why don't you go with dropdowns? Dropdowns are designed precisely for the purpose you are describing. Date pickers can also be considered a type of dropdown, so you are consistent.

I don't think Chips fit your scenario for two reasons (based on their [guidelines](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/guidelines)):

1. Chips are contextual, while your components are predetermined (as far as I understood).
2. You know your component is always used for a single purpose (choosing an option). Chips are designed for a *set of actions*. Google discourages using a single chip, while in your app I assume every form entry would have one chip.